# UiBinder How To : create resuable component in ui.xml

Tags: gwt

I have this component with a `@UiConstrutor` annotation :

```
@UiConstructor
public SearchWidget(Widget filterWidget, Widget resultWidget) {
  ...
}
```

in the ui.xml, I must write something like :

```
<SearchWidget filterWidget="" resultWidget=""/>
```

The problem is that I would like to be able to build a complex widget apart in ui.xml and use in the `<SearchWidget>` tag, something like :

```
<with field="filterWidget">
  <Widget>
  ...
  </Widget>
</with>

<With field="resultWidget">
  <Widget>
  ...
  </Widget>
</with>
```

And then use it like :

```
<SearchWidget filterWidget="{filterWidget}" resultWidget="{resultWidget}"/>
```

Is their an existing approaching syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `@UiChild` annotation (if you can replace constructor dependencies by corresponding methods). See [corresponding javadoc](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/uibinder/client/UiChild.html) with example.

Two new methods:

```
@UiChild SearchWidget#addFilterWidget(Widget w)
@UiChild SearchWidget#addResultWidget(Widget w)
```

UiBinder (you need to declare new `p` namespace for your custom widgets):

```
<p:SearchWidget>
    <p:filterWidget><p:Widget>...</p:Widget></p:filterWidget>
    <p:resultWidget><p:Widget>...</p:Widget></p:resultWidget>
</p:SearchWidget>
```

Comment: Why do you have to wrap the widget twice?

why can't it just be <p:FilterWidget/>?

Comment: @Zerkz, `<p:filterWidget>` is not a widget in this case. It is a call for `SearchWidget#addFilterWidget(Widget w)` method. As you can see you need to pass a parameter and in this case it is `<p:Widget>...</p:Widget>`. Check the javadoc mentioned in my answer, you'll find more detailed example.